# WKWebView App crash when press "Shift" using Hardware KeyBoard iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using `WKWebView`, when I try to insert any values in `WebPage` using **HardWare KeyBoard** app getting crashed. It's always crashing when i Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Any Other Key</kbd> with my **External KeyBoard**.

> Note:- i already tried `webview.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` with `true` and `false` both

- I already tried with following solutions but won't work for me
  [WKWebView crashes if user answers an incoming iMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45163059/11077258).
  [WKWebview with the new iOS13 modal crash when a file picker is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58164583/11077258).
  [iOS11 WKWebview crash due to NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47142434/11077258)
- **Crash Log**

```
2021-04-14 19:05:25.253969+0530 ZapDial[13417:318028] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff512a19b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ed09d1 _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23edb426 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:].cold.4 + 38
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e9c6e7 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 247
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39d71 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 49
    6   UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff4877c634 AXUIAutomationHandleKeyComplete + 200
    7   WebKitLegacy                        0x000000011c197592 sendNotificationAfterHandlingWebKeyEventIfNeeded + 144
    8   WebKitLegacy                        0x000000011c1974ee -[DOMNodeAccessibility handleKeyWebEvent:] + 72
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e44dec __invoking___ + 140
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e41fd1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 321
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e422a4 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 68
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff498c7b79 -[UIThreadSafeNode forwardInvocation:] + 92
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e42616 ___forwarding___ + 838
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e44b58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49192ccb -[UIKeyboardImpl _handleWebKeyEvent:withEventType:withInputString:withInputStringIgnoringModifiers:executionContext:] + 635
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49194b14 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleModifiersChangeForKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 528
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff491a965d -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:] + 147
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff491a8173 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 310
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49193ec6 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 201
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e44dec __invoking___ + 140
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e41fd1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 321
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4971d9a1 -[UIRepeatedAction invoke] + 278
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4971dba1 -[UIRepeatedAction _preInvocationTimerFire] + 45
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4938d523 -[UIApplication _handleKeyboardPressEvent:] + 2214
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49377487 -[UIApplication pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 401
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48bf7489 -[UITabBarController pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 115
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    39  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    40  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    41  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    42  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    43  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    44  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    45  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    46  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    47  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    48  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    49  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    50  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    51  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    52  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    53  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    54  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    55  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    56  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    57  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    58  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    59  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a045a forwardTouchMethod + 323
    60  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a4182 -[UIResponder pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 49
    61  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493afde8 -[UIWindow _sendButtonsForEvent:] + 393
    62  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493b0dbd -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3273
    63  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4938b6cd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    64  UIKit                               0x00000001140260b8 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 85
    65  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4938c356 -[UIApplication _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 627
    66  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    67  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    68  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    69  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    70  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    71  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    72  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    73  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    74  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    75  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    76  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    77  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    78  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    79  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    80  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    81  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    82  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493a3705 -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    83  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4938c402 -[UIApplication handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    84  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4938c0c2 -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 535
    85  UIKit                               0x000000011401fb05 -[UIApplicationAccessibility handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 41
    86  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49415781 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 4227
    87  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4941968e __handleEventQueueInternal + 6584
    88  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4940ff31 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 88
    89  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1c91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    90  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1bbc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    91  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1394 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    92  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9bf8e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    93  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    94  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38c05bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
    95  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49372964 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    96  ZapDial                             0x000000010c7fab2b main + 75
    97  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5211c1fd start + 1
    98  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```